# How to curl item that doesn't happen on pageLoad

Tags: javascript, curl

I am trying to get the Title of a movie on IMDb:

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049902/

However, if I do:

```
$ curl http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049902/
```

The Title that is contained is **Un condamné à mort s'est échappé ou Le vent souffle où il veut**, not "A Man Escaped", which is what I want. Here is the HTML from the curl response:

```
<h1 class="header"> <span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Un condamné à mort s'est échappé ou Le vent souffle où il veut</span>
        <span class="nobr">(<a href="/year/1956/?ref_=tt_ov_inf"
>1956</a>)</span>
</h1>
```

It looks like the English title must be inserted after the initial page load. How would I fetch this title then?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a way to get it strictly from the initial HTML dump you're getting from curl. Perhaps it's better to use their [official API](http://www.omdbapi.com/) instead of scraping their web page.

Comment: if it's not in the source then it's likely injected with script. You would need a headless browser to get generated html

Comment: Actually, as I just answered, it looks like all you need is to specify the appropriate `Accept-Language` header -- so I believe javascript is not involved (but I'm not sure so I left that tag in) though I'm 100% sure that python isn't (so I did remove that stray tag).  Seconded @HuuNguyen's suggestion to prefer official APIs over scraping, anyway:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ curl --header "Accept-Language: en"  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049902/ > b.txt
$ grep 'meta.*title' b.txt
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049902/" />
<meta property='og:title' content="A Man Escaped (1956)" />
<meta name="title" content="A Man Escaped (1956) - IMDb" />
```

so it seems that the `--header "Accept-Language: en"` helps in this case (while, without specifying that header, you're getting the movie's original language - French).